# Connect ionic radio button form to a firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I have created an ionic app which contains a radio button form. I have a problem connecting the radio button form to  the firebase realtime database. The database should be able to store radio values selected by a user after submission. I have already added firebase to my ionic app.

This is my code

```
<form [formGroup]="ngForm" (submit)="submit()">
   <ion-list>
     <ion-radio-group formControlName="radioSelection">
       <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Option 1</ion-label>
          <ion-radio slot="start" value="1"></ion-radio>
       </ion-item>
       <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Option 2</ion-label>
          <ion-radio slot="start" value="2"></ion-radio>
       </ion-item>
     </ion-radio-group>
  </ion-list>
</form>
```

The .ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-four',
  templateUrl: './four.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./four.page.scss'],
})
export class FourPage implements OnInit {

  ngForm: FormGroup;
  radioValue: any;


  constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private fdb: AngularFireDatabaseModule
               ) {
                this.ngForm = new FormGroup({
                  radioSelection: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
                  });
              }

 database = firebase.database();
ref = this.database.ref('ngForm');



ngOnInit() {
  }


  submitForm() {
     this.radioValue = this.ngForm.get('radioSelection').value;
     this.ref.push(this.ngForm);

}
}
```

If you also have an idea of how to submit this form to a firestore database, you can also add your answer

Comment: Which version of ionic are you using? Ionic 1-5? With angular? With react? With native javascript? Also some sample code would be helpful

Comment: I am using ionic 4 with angular

Comment: Which underlying framework are you using? Angular? And please share your code

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it seems you are using Ionic 4 with Angular. With angular reactive forms you can do it like this

```
<form [formGroup]="yourForm" (submit)="submit()">
   <ion-list>
     <ion-radio-group formControlName="radioSelection">
       <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Option 1</ion-label>
          <ion-radio slot="start" value="1"></ion-radio>
       </ion-item>
       <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Option 2</ion-label>
          <ion-radio slot="start" value="2"></ion-radio>
       </ion-item>
     </ion-radio-group>
  </ion-list>
</form>
```

What i can tell from your code snipped is that you are missing the name property on the radio-group for the form.

In your .ts file then have something like this

```
yourForm: FormGroup

constructor() {
   this.yourForm = new FormGroup({
     radioSelection: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
   })
}

submit() {
  const radioValue = this.yourForm.get('radioSelection').value;
  // send it to your database
}
```

This is using Reactive forms so make sure to import the ReactiveFormsModule into your component.module.ts